# Question in "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring W. Tu in taylors theorm

Tags: manifolds, taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

In Tu's book, specifically the section on "Taylor's Theorem with remainder" page 7,
Let  be a ∞ function on an open set ⊆ℝ which is star shaped with respect to a point =(1,...,)∈. Then there are functions $_1()$,...,$_$()∈∞

such that

$()= f(p)+ ∑(x^i − p^i )g_i(x)$
, where $()=\frac{\\∂}{∂}(p)$.

by chain rule

$\frac{\\d}{dt}f(p+t(x−p))=∑(x^i−p^i)\frac{\\∂}{∂^i}(p+t(x−p))$.

If we integrate both sides with respect to t from 0 to 1, we get
$ [f(p+t(x− p))]^1_0 = ∑(x^i − p^i) \int_0^1 \frac{\\∂}{∂^i} (p+t(x− p))dt$.

$g_i(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\\∂}{∂^i}(p+t(x− p))dt$

Then gi(x) is C∞ and (1.1) becomes

$f(x)− f(p) = ∑(x^i − p^i)g_i(x)$.

$\frac{\\d}{dt}f(p+t(x−p))=∑(x^i−p^i)∂f(p+t(x−p))$.

Then later on  he goes on to to say:

Moreover,

$g_i(p)=\int_0^1 \frac{\\∂}{∂}(p)dt$=$\frac{\\∂}{∂}(p)$

In case n=1and p=0,this lemma says that

$f(x) = f(0)+xg_1(x)$

for some C∞ function $g_1(x)$. Applying the lemma repeatedly gives

$g_i(x)=g_i(0)+xg_{i+1}(x)$

where $g_{i}$, $g_{i+1}$ are C∞ functions. Hence,

$f(x)= f(0)+x(g_{1}(0)+xg_{2}(x))$

= $f(0)+xg_{1}(0)+x^2(g_{2}(0)+xg_{3}(x))$

= $f(0)+xg_{1}(0)+x^2g_{2}(0)+...x^ig_{i}(0)+x^{i+1}g_{i+1}(x)$ (1.2)

I do not understand how he jumped from 1.2 to

Differentiating (1.2) repeatedly and evaluating at 0, we get

$g_k(0)=\  \frac{\\f^k(0)}{k!}$   $k=1,2,.....i.$

This is my first post so appolgies if i messed up the format.

Comment: differentiate both sides of the equation and evaluate at 0. Try this for small values of k

Comment: @peek-a-boo i have just realized that , thank you so much !!